# Django TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have these Django models:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent_group = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Block(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    app = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Lets say that block **b1** has the **g1** group. By it's name I want to get **all blocks** from group **g1**. I wrote this recursive function:

```
def get_blocks(group):
    
    def get_needed_blocks(group):
        for block in group.block_set:
            blocks.append(block)

        if group.parent_group is not None:
            get_needed_blocks(group.parent_group)

    blocks = []
    get_needed_blocks(group)
    return blocks
```

But **b1.group.block_set** returns a **RelatedManager** object, which is not iterable.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Try this:

```
block in group.block_set.all()
```

Comment: Does anyone know why RelatedManager is not made to be iterable?  I would have expected it to be that way...

Comment: This comment is a little late, but the reasoning is that you can use the filtering methods on the manager in order to restrict the query before performing a fetch to the db.

Comment: @stalepretzel, because it works exactly as a standard django manager. You don't call Model.objects and iterate over it. You call Model.objects.all() and then you iterate. Django manager =/= Django queryset.

Comment: and if you are using it in a template for loop you can do {% for object in objects.other_object_set.all %}

Comment: @stalepretzel ...especially since it's called a "blocks_SET" - and not a "blocks_relatedmanager". Or "blocks_set_relatedmanager".

Answer (score 33):

Use it [like a `Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/). If you want all the objects then call the `all()` method.

Answer (score 17):

you have to use .all() with related name or childModel_set model name .

in views.py use :

```
for item in object.relatedname.all():
    do something ......
```

in html templates use:

```
 {% for item in object.relatedname.all %}
   do something ......
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but could you explain why this is the mechanism and how it works? I am just a bit confused that what makes difference between having those paranthesis and not having them.
 Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you are expiriencing this error in Django template try:

```
{% for block in group.block_set.all %}
{{ block }}
{% endfor %}
```