# How can small queries be combined in django rest framework with nested serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a database relationship like the following:

```
  +-----------+
  | Container |
  +-----------+
  | id        |
  +-----------+
        | 
        |1..n 
+--------------+
| Child        |
+--------------+
| id           |
| container_id |
+--------------+
```

I want to nest the serializers for the `Child` in the `Container` serializer so I can get both objects in one HTTP request.  However, when I query for a list of `Containers`, Django REST Framework does a single query to get all the `Containers`, but then does a bunch of individual queries for each set of `Child` objects associated with a specific `Container` object.  Here is my toy example:

```
# Models
class Container(models.Model):
    pass

class Child(models.Model):
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container,related_name="children")

# Serializers
class ChildSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('url','container')

class ContainerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    children = ChildSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Container
        fields = ('url','children')

# Views
class ContainerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet)
    queryset = Container.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContainerSerializer

class ChildViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet)
    queryset = Child.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChildSerializer
```

Is there a way to coalesce all the `Child` queries into one backend query and then distribute the results amongst the `Container` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django REST Framework will not optimize your queries for you, it's up to you to decide how best to remove any N+1 queries. You should follow the guidelines covered in [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/) to handle performance issues.

In the case of ForeignKey relationships, you should use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) in your query, which will pre-fetch the objects in the original query.

In the case of ManyToMany and GenericForeignKey relationships, you should use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related). I've written quite a bit about this in [another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26598897/359284), but the gist is that you use it similar to `select_related`.

You should override the query in `get_queryset` on the view for best results, as you don't need to worry about Django REST Framework incorrectly cloning the queryset when used as an attribute on the class.