# Django serialize multiple objects in one call

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was wondering how I can decrease the number of calls to my database when serializing:

I have the following 2 models:

```
 class House(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)
     address = models.CharField(max_length = 500, null = True, blank = True)

 class Room(models.Model):
      house = models.ForeignKey(House)
      name  = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

There is 1 house, it can have multiple Room.

I am using django-rest-framework and trying to serialize all 3 things together at the house level.

```
 class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    rooms = serializers.SerializerMethodField('room_serializer')

    def room_serializer(self):
         rooms = Room.objects.filter(house_id = self.id) # we are in House serializer, so self is a house
         return RoomSerializer(rooms).data

    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'address')
```

So now, for every house I want to serialize, I need to make a separate call for its Rooms.  It works, but that's an extra call.
(imagine me trying to package a lot of stuff together!)

Now, if I had 100 houses, to serialize everything, I would need to make 100 Database hits, O(n) time

I know I can decrease this to 2 hits, if I can get all the information together. O(1) time

```
my_houses = Houses.objects.filter(name = "mine")
my_rooms = Rooms.objects.filter(house_id__in = [house.id for house in my_houses])
```

My question is how can I do this? and get the serializers to be happy?

Can I somehow do a loop after doing my two calls, to "attach" a Room to a House, then serialize it?  (am I allowed to add an attribute like that?)  If I can, how do i get my serializer to read it?

Please note that I do not need django-rest-serializer to allow me to change the attributes in the Rooms, this way.  This is for GET only.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As it is currently writen, using a `SerializerMethodField`, you are making N+1 queries. I have covered this a few times on Stack Overflow for [optimizing the database queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26598897/359284) and in general, it's similar to how you would [improve the performance in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/). You are dealing with a one-to-many relationship, which can be optimized the same way as many-to-many relationships with `prefetch_related`.

```
class HouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    rooms = RoomSerializer(read_only=True, source="room_set", many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'address', )
```

The change I made uses nested serializers instead of manually generating the serializer within a `SerializerMethodField`. I had restricted it to be `read_only`, as you mentioned you only need it for `GET` requests and writable serializers have problems in Django REST Framework 2.4.

As your reverse relationship for the `Room` -> `House` relationship has not been set, it is the default `room_set`. You can (and should) override this by setting the `related_name` on the `ForeignKey` field, and you would need to adjust the `source` accordingly.

In order to prevent the N+1 query issue, you will need to override the queryset on your view. In the case of a generic view, this would be done on the `queryset` attribute or within the `get_queryset` method like `queyset = House.objects.prefetch_related('room_set')`. This will request all of the related rooms alongisde the request for the `House` object, so instead of N+1 requests you will only have two requests.