# Django: select_related on a very simple relationship is not eliminating the N+1 problem

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-select-related

I have a strange situation. I've done so much reading on avoiding the `N+1` problem and have tried prefetching but to no avail. My setup is like this:

Models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    somefield1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    somefield2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    # Assume that classes Y and Z exist. We don't care about them.
    y = models.ForeignKey(Y, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    z = models.ForeignKey(Z, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class B(models.Model)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="b_objs")
```

Visually:

```
B --> A --> Y and Z (Again, we don't care about A's FKs to Y and Z)
```

There are `188 A objects` and `1291 B objects` pointing to some combination of those 188 As.

I do a simple query like so:

```
list(B.objects.select_related('a'))
```

When I log my django DB queries (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161527/194707), I see over 1000 calls to select individual elements of A like so (most likely because we have 1291 B objects, each of which points to one A object):

```
SELECT "A"."id",
       "A"."somefield1",
       "A"."somefield2",
       "A"."y_id",
       "A"."z_id"
       FROM "A"
       WHERE "A"."id" = 109 LIMIT 21; args=(109,); alias=default
```

The value of `A.id` (109) changes every query, presumably for each B object that points to one A object.

The `select_related` is doing something because I see the correct `INNER JOIN` in the first query to connect `A` and `B`, as well as get all of `A`'s fields:

```
SELECT "B"."id",
       "B"."a_id",
       "A"."id",
       "A"."somefield1",
       "A"."somefield2",
       "A"."y_id",
       "A"."z_id"
       FROM "A" INNER JOIN "B" ON ("B"."a_id" = "A"."id")
```

In fact, this query returns everything that we would hypothetically need to build all the models! It returns 1291 rows, which is correct.

Futhermore, when I print

```
print(B.objects.select_related('a').query)
```

It only returns that one query above, not the 1291 other ones.

**Where are each of the individual queries for each A object coming from then?**

**And does anyone know why calling select_related on `a` doesn't prevent these thousands of individual queries for A from happening?**

Doing something more extreme like

```
list(B.objects.select_related())
```

or even

```
list(B.objects.select_related().prefetch_related())
```

to follow all foreign keys and relations only makes the first query with the `INNER JOIN` much more complicated, but it still results in `N` queries for each of the 1291 A objects pointing to B objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my `select_related` was correct. The culprit was a `post_init` receiver on `B` that was calling `self.b.a`, which resulted in the individual queries for each `A` object every time a `B` object was instantiated. Painful lesson learned.

For those facing similar issues, I was able to debug this using this amazing SQL stacktrace tool which prints a python stacktrace of where the query is being generated: https://github.com/dobarkod/django-queryinspect.